# Unable to select different account on google login for android using kotlin

Tags: android, authentication, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have implemented Google Signing for Android app. The user can successfully login from the Google Login Button.
So now the user has logged in successfully by selecting his/her account.

Now, user logs out and tries to sign in again by using Google Login Button.

At this time, he is not asked with the option to choose account , he is automatically logged in using the account he/she selected at the first time.

At the time of logout what should I do to clear the cache of selected account.(using kotlin)

Comment: Add your code for signing out to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Sign out from your GoogleSignInClient as well. You can use this:

```
private fun logout() {
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

    val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso)
    googleSignInClient.signOut()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the [One Tap UI (google login successor)](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials) one must set `setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts` to false like this:

```java
BeginSignInRequest signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
                .setPasswordRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
                        .setSupported(false)
                        .build())
                .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                        .setSupported(true)
                        // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                        .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                        // Don't show only accounts previously used to sign in.
                        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                        .build())
                // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
                .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
                .build();
```

then the One Tap UI will show other google accounts connected on the device.